# When exactly MySQL locks a row on updating InnoDB table?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, rowlocking

If I have this multiupdate query

```
UPDATE user u
INNER JOIN user_profile up ON up.user_id = u.id
SET u.name = 'same_name_i_already_had', up.profile.age = 25
WHERE u.id = 10
```

Let's suppose the row 10 in user table already has the name 'same_name_i_already_had', so it shouldn't be updated.
On the other hand, the row in user_profile table has a different age, so MySQL should update it.
Assuming **MySQL** as RDBMS and **InnoDB** with its row level locking system as the engine of both tables,
**Does MySQL lock the row in user table in spite of not having to update the name field of that row?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does lock the row in `user`.  You can verify this using the excellent [innotop](http://code.google.com/p/innotop/) tool.

- Run innotop and press the 'L' key to display a screen of InnoDB locks.
- Open another session, log into MySQL and START TRANSACTION.
- Execute the UPDATE you showed, but do not COMMIT yet.
- View the locks in the innotop screen.

For example, I created tables user and user_profile on my test VM running MySQL 5.5, and I performed the steps I list above.  Here's the output:

```
[RO] Locks (? for help) localhost, 08:34.568, InnoDB 10s :-), 0.10 QPS, 2/0/0 con/run/cac thds, 5.5.

__________________________________________ InnoDB Locks __________________________________________
ID  Type    Waiting  Wait   Active  Mode  DB    Table         Index    Ins Intent  Special        
 2  TABLE         0  00:00   02:35  IX    test  user                            0                 
 2  RECORD        0  00:00   02:35  X     test  user          PRIMARY           0  rec but not gap
 2  TABLE         0  00:00   02:35  IX    test  user_profile                    0                 
 2  RECORD        0  00:00   02:35  X     test  user_profile  PRIMARY           0  rec but not gap
```

Comment: Excellent answer, however i do not understand the TABLE locks shown. Could you explain what innotop means?

Comment: The "IX" mode is a table-level lock meaning "I *intend* to lock some rows in this table."  It won't block row-level locks on the same table, but it will block table-level locks.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-lock-modes.html for a full explanation of InnoDB locking, and http://innotop.googlecode.com/svn/html/manual.html for full explanation of using innotop.

Comment: Best answer I've ever had. Thank you very much!

Comment: How does someone "Execute the UPDATE you showed, but do not COMMIT yet". I am new to MySQL and am trying to profile some updates.

Comment: @PeterA, start a transaction with the statement "BEGIN;" that means to avoid autocommit of every statement. The transaction will be held open until you explicitly use "COMMIT;" or "ROLLBACK;" For more information, read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Answer (score 4):

Almost surely it locks the row regardless.  I don't know of any simple fields which are checked for a change first.  It is easier and faster to just lock, write, and unlock.  If there were a check before locking, then there is a race condition:  something which a lock completely avoids.